# Why I am getting an empty array?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview, mvvm

I want to transfer all the data which is in Detail Page to the Cart Page which is tableView. My main question is that in the CartScreen page an array is still empty even if in Detail Screen I pressed add to cart button (which works fine). I am using MVVM design so here's is a **repo class**:

```
class FoodsDaoRepository {
    var foodList = BehaviorSubject <[Foods]>(value: [Foods]())
    var cartList = BehaviorSubject <[FoodsCart]>(value: [FoodsCart]())

     var cartList = BehaviorSubject <[FoodsCart]>(value: [FoodsCart]())

      func getFromCart (userName: String) {
        let params: Parameters = ["userName" : userName]
        AF.request("http://example.com/foods/getFoodsCart.php", method: .post, parameters: params).response {response in
            if let data = response.data {
                do{
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(CartResponse.self, from: data)
                    if let list = result.cart {
                        self.cartList.onNext(list)
                        print(list)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Cart Response class**

```
struct CartResponse : Codable {
var cart : [FoodsCart]? }
```

**FoodsCart class**

```
class FoodsCart : Codable {
var cartId : Int
var name : String
var image : String
var price : Int
var category : String
var orderAmount : Int
var userName = "rustin_wilde"

 init(cartId: Int, name: String, image: String, price: Int, category: String, orderAmount: Int, userName: String = "rustin_wilde") {
    self.cartId = cartId
    self.name = name
    self.image = image
    self.price = price
    self.category = category
    self.orderAmount = orderAmount
    self.userName = userName
}
```

}

**Product table view cell class**

```
class ProductsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var productImageCart: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var productNameCart: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var productCategory: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var productAmountCart: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var productTotalPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var userName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var viewCart: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func configure(item : FoodsCart) {
    
    let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/foods/images/" + item.image)
    productImageCart.kf.setImage(with: url)
    productNameCart.text = item.name
    productCategory.text = item.category
    productTotalPrice.text = "\(item.price)"
    productAmountCart.text = String(item.price)
    userName.text = item.userName
    
}}
```

**CartScreen class**

```
    class CartScreen : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var cartTableView: UITableView!
    
    var cart : FoodsCart?
    var foodsCart = [FoodsCart]()
    var viewModel = CartViewModel()
    
   public var userName = "rustin_wilde"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        let _ = viewModel.cartList.subscribe(onNext: { list in
            self.foodsCart = list
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.cartTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
        
        cartTableView.delegate = self
        cartTableView.dataSource = self
        
        //register xib
        cartTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ProductsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProductsTableViewCell")      
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        viewModel.getFromCart(userName: userName)
        
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return foodsCart.count
    }
 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let foodCart = foodsCart[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productCell") as! ProductsTableViewCell
        cell.configure(item: foodCart)
        return cell        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code where you add to (or set) the array?

Comment: how to add in this situation all the information to the array? Sorry I am new in Swift

Comment: There is not enough information to answer that, I don't even understand what it is you want to add or where it is supposed to come from